# Can't change CUBE_MAX_DIM Postgresql

Tags: windows, python, postgresql

I have a problem with Postgresql
I'm truying to change max dim of cube extention
The official guide of Postgresql:
"To make it harder for people to break things, there is a limit of 100 on the number of dimensions of cubes. This is set in cubedata.h if you need something bigger"
I changed it to 128, but when i'm trying to test i have the same error "DETAIL:  A cube cannot have more than 100 dimensions."
Should i somehow rebuild postgresql or recompile cube extention?
Windows 10
postgresql 9.6
And postgresql 11 the same story..  :(

Comment: “I changed a ```.h``` file … should I recompile?” Yes.

Answer (score -1):

Look here for updated PSQL in docker
https://github.com/unoexperto/docker-postgresql-large-cube/blob/master/README.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/860054)

Comment: I can remove my answer, if you wish, sir.